# Bayesian method to determine effect size

Tags: bayesian, effect-size

I have data on heights of 2 groups of persons. Usually [Cohen's-d](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Cohen's_d) is used to determine effect size.

Is there any Bayesian equivalent of Cohen's-d which reflects effect size of the difference between 2 groups? I tried to search the Internet but could not find an easy answer. Thanks for your insight.